# Itemfreq() in SciPy raises error 'NotImplementedType' object has no attribute 'flat'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following packages, which I am sadly unable to upgrade:

- Numpy: 1.8.2
- SciPy: 0.13.3

I need to count the frequencies of a string variable in a numpy array, which I want to do using the SciPy method `itemfreq()`. However, I get the following error when running it. How can this be resolved?

```
  File "my_script.py", line 29, in count_uniq
    freq = itemfreq(dat)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 1465, in itemfreq
    scores = _support.unique(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_support.py", line 50, in unique
    if np.add.reduce(np.equal(uniques,item).flat) == 0:
AttributeError: 'NotImplementedType' object has no attribute 'flat'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/maintenance/0.13.x/scipy/stats/_support.py) and the docstring reports that the function `unique()` (which is part of scipy.stats) doesn't work on arrays with strings.

One way to get around this is to map the strings to numeric values and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

From `AttributeError: 'NotImplementedType' object has no attribute 'flat'`, I suspect `NotImplemented` is from the `np.equal(uniques,item)` part.

The dimension of `uniques` and `item` is likely not the same. It looks like the `item` will be of `m` shape and uniques will be of `n` shape and the resultant should be of `(m, n)` shape.  If so, Change it to `item == np.array(list('uniques'))[...,np.newaxis]` might solve the problem.